# strategy pattern and variables with interfaces

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a this java application i am working on to get more experience with design patterns and OODesign. The application allows the user to select "equations" from a list. And then the user will be prompted with parameters for the selected equation and will be given a button to press to solve the equations.

I am implementing the equations as a strategy pattern. I am trying to figure out how to get the names of the equations into the list box. I was wondering if there was a way for the Equation classes that implement the EquationInterface to have a variable called equationName. That would allow the programmer to assign the specific equation a name when they are coding up the class for that specific equation. Code is listed below.

Example: When the programmer is designing a new equation to add to the program, they are required to include a name for the strategy created.

If you have any questions, please let me know. I am having a hard time explaining what i am trying to accomplish. And if you have any suggestions on a better design patter to use or way of accomplishing this goal, please let me know.

```
public class Equation {
    public enum equationList {
        DISTANCETRAVELLEDFALLINGOVERTIME,
        TIMEFOROBJECTFALLDISTANCE
    }

    private EquationInterface solveInterface;

    public Equation(EquationInterface solveInterface) {
        this.solveInterface = solveInterface;
    }

    public void solve() {
        solveInterface.performSolve();
    }

    public JPanel getParameterPanel() {
        return solveInterface.createParameterPanel();
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface EquationInterface {

    public JPanel createParameterPanel();

    public void performSolve();
}
```

---

```
public class DistanceTravelledFallingOverTime implements EquationInterface {

    @Override
    public void performSolve() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("DistanceTravelledFallingOverTime");
    }

    @Override
    public JPanel createParameterPanel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there something preventing you from having `EquationInterface` include a `getEquationName()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface EquationInterface {

    public JPanel createParameterPanel();

    public void performSolve();

    public void setEquationName(String equationName);
    public String getEquationName();
}
```

I would use getter type method instead of a variable.

One sample implementation

```
public class  SampleEquation implements EquationInterface {

    public JPanel createParameterPanel(){return null;}

    public void performSolve(){
    //solving an equation
    }

    private String equationName = "MyDefaultEquationName";// or = null

    public void setEquationName(String equationName){
      this.equationName = equationName;
    }

    public String getEquationName(){
      return this.equationName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would the EquationName variable be directly associated with the created equation? What variable would "getEquationName()" be retrieving?

Comment: Would the coder just have to include the variable in each individual equation he/she added?

Comment: One way is to use Abstract class instead of interface if you don't want to repeat yourself (DRY principle). Or you must provide private String equationName in classes implementing EquationInterface.

Comment: That is what i thought my options were. I am trying to not use abstract class in this implementation. Been a long morning, brain is hurting... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with adding a `getEquationName()` into the `EquationInterface` interface:

```
public interface EquationInterface {

    public JPanel createParameterPanel();

    public void performSolve();

    public String getEquationName();
}
```

Sample implementation would look like:

```
public class DistanceTravelledFallingOverTime implements EquationInterface {

    @Override
    public void performSolve() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("DistanceTravelledFallingOverTime");
    }

    @Override
    public JPanel createParameterPanel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEquationName(){
      return "Distance Travelled Falling Over Time";
    }

}
```

Furthermore, I would suggest another improvement in your design. Take a look at the `EquationInterface` interface; it looks a bit thick to me. It contains the `getEquationName()` and `performSolve()` methods which make a lot of sense. They are both concerned with the actual functionality of an equation. However, having a UI related method such as `createParameterPanel()` looks very odd to me. The interface now has a dependency on `JPanel` class and it is somehow tied to the UI. I would really break the interface into two; `EquationInterface` would contain the naming and the solution, while another interface would serve as to create the UI elements.

That also kind of answers your worries about the strategy pattern; the `EquationInterface` now  would only be linked to the actual logic of an equation, including the name. In other words, it should feel more natural to add the naming logic into the interface. More details on this topic of interface segregation can be found [here.](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/isp.pdf)

Comment: I need the parameter panel to contain the parameters associated with the specific equation. So, if a coder wants to add a new equation they will have to create the equation class and then add their code for what they want the jpanel to look like. Each equation could have a varying amount of parameters, so i was going to leave that up to the equation creator to create the panel when they create the equation class and they would use the solve method to grab all the inputs from the panel they crated... what would i need to do for this?

Comment: it makes sense that the `EquationInterface` contains the logic for parameters; parameters are vital part of the equation. However, the JPanel coupling is the problem. Here is what you can do: Create a class called `EquationParameter` and add the method `List<EquationParameter> getParameters()` to the `EquationInterface` interface. Notice how coherent the interface has become with 3 decoupled methods: getName, getParameters, performSolve. An equation implementation has to provide name & parameters and solution; very natural.

Comment: Another good side of this approach: The JPanel creation and modification code can now be handled in one place. The concrete equation implementations don't have to deal with JPanel; they only have to create instances of `EquationParameter`. There will be a code (more like a utility code) that takes this list of equation parameters and creates JPanels out of it.